# 4OD wont stream on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hal

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12 and cannot get 4od to stream.

I have tried getting hal, as suggested for the same problem with 13.10, from the repository but it still does nothing. When I hit play I just get the loading circle forever :(

I have tried reinstalling the flash player but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I too have attempted both deleting the adobe cache and installing hal to the same outcome. It seems only newer videos are affected as  series from 2009 work fine but anything newer yields the same loading circle problem.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended [here](http://nlug.ml1.co.uk/2014/03/4od-on-ubuntu-and-related/4652), try deleting the Adobe cache:

Close Firefox (or at least any tabs that are actively using Flash) and delete the Adobe cache using this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.adobe
```

You will need to do this for every user on the affected system. This will cause you to lose Flash cookies and other information, so Flash games like "Machinarium" will be affected.

If that concerns you, either back-up the important information or navigate into the cache and be more strategic on what you delete.